# Resharper throwing Possible 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, resharper

I have written the below code but resharper is throwing

> Possible 'System.InvalidOperationException'

What could be the reason?

```
Assert.Null(actual.Items?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date.Value.Year == 2019).Growth);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault` call may return `null` and you'll get an exception when accessing `Growth` property, try to use null conditional operator `?.` one more time, like `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date.Value.Year == 2019)?.Growth`. It allows to avoid a `NullReferenceException`

As for `InvalidOperationException`, `x.Date` seems to have a `Nullable<DateTime>` type, you should use `HasValue` property before getting a `Value`, like `x => x.Date.HasValue && x.Date.Value.Year == 2019`. Or [`GetValueOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netcore-3.1#System_Nullable_1_GetValueOrDefault) method `x => x.Date.GetValueOrDefault().Year == 2019`. Or even simper `?.` operator again `x => x.Date?.Year == 2019`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check for the

actual.Items?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date.Value.Year == 2019) to be null first and then go for
take it in variable as

```
var currentItem = actual.Items?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date.Value.Year == 2019);
Assert.Null(currentItem .Growth);
```